# Algolia not finding record

Tags: algolia

I have a record with a title "Raw masterclass" and the "title" field is in the attributes to index.

If I type "raw" on the search bar, I get zero records found.

This doesn't make sense...

Comment: This doesn't make sense indeed. Are you sure you don't have a typo or trailing/leading whitespace in the attribute name?

Comment: Also, did you try using the Algolia web dashboard? Or just from your code?

Comment: Hey @redox! No, there's no type or whitespace. I'm testing from the dash. Here's a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5d52tb17qvqvwv/Screenshot%202016-10-02%2017.39.53.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Also, I've found one weird thing. If I add a ony-way synonym (raw > vegan or vegetarian), it does find, although this record doesn't have "vegan" or "vegetarian" anywhere. Another screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wko9xl69wes9ugo/Screenshot%202016-10-02%2017.41.39.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Oh I think I know. We have a weird option (default true) called "Settings > Display > Replace synonyms in highlight" which replaces the word by its alternative form in the highlighting. I'm almost sure your record is not "raw masterclass" but "Vegetarian masterclass" and therefore you don't find it without the synonym.

Comment: You are absolutely right! My bad. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the "Settings > Display > Replace synonyms in highlight" index settings? This replaces the word by its alternative form in the highlighting and I'm almost sure your record is not "raw masterclass" but "Vegetarian masterclass" and therefore you don't find it without a `raw <> vegatarian` synonym.